# Opposite of "under the weather"?

Tags: formality, phrase-requests

British TV Shows are a good way to learn language. At the moment I'm watching Situation Comedy classic series *Black Adder*, Season one on DVD format. I learnt a new phrase "under the weather" which is in script in Season 1, episode 5, "Witchsmeller Pursuivant".

My own funny moment down at the real life.
It was snowing during pre-season Christmas here in Finland. Some local immigrant said "Hello" to me and then continued his small talk "Bad weather, I've moved to Finland last summer and it's snowing, very horrible weather." I answered him: "Well, I'm *under the weather too* like you here in winter-time Finland".

I was referring to bad weather but I don't know if he caught the joke. Is there an opposite phrase for "Under the weather". "Ylaepuolella" in Finnish synonym in English translation is something like above, on top, over, upstairs, aloft, overhead.

Is it idiomatic to say "I'm feeling overhead" when my mood is good? Looking for a legit way to express myself feeling good as opposed to "under the weather".

In another joke for *feeling overheaded*, if it's a legit way to cite like this.

Tall and the Giant man met each others on the street. Tall man began the small-talk daily conversation as strangers:

> "Howdy Hootchie-Cootchie, How do you do?" The Giant answered "How Do You Do? I'm feelin' overheaded".

Overhead, or another legit way to express yourself feeling good in a positive way or in a joke when I'm trying to create funny situation comedy? Or in polite manner in daily use in GB England, not in US English.

Comment: *On top of the world*, *over the moon*, *through the roof*, but not overhead.

Comment: Be careful; Blackadder tends to disregard established rules interfrastically. More seriously, 'under the weather' usually refers to feeling ill.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to draw on a similar metaphor you could say "over the rainbow".

Comment: @HotLicks somewhere, somewhere you may find a suitable metaphor... LOL

Comment: Now I can understand Classic Music after your opening, Yosef, song "Fly me to the moon" and after they flew to the moon feelings could be over the rainbow. Never thought about that even I'm music enthusiastic. "Over the Rainbow" is an other classic piece. I like Tommy Emmanuel Cover Version especially.

Comment: I follow Finnish translation on my DVD for Black Adder script choices for Finnish synonyms translated by Professional linguist and there's "Under the Weather" translated such a "Feeling ill" in a way of Finnish language semantics..

Comment: Phrases like ‘over the moon’, ‘on top of the world’, and ‘over the rainbow’ seem to be much stronger than (as well as in the opposite direction from) ‘under the weather’.  Also, they're about mood, while the latter is more about health (i.e. feeling slightly unwell).

Comment: British English translation of 'under the weather' only means 'not feeling too well'. It has little bearing actually on the weather, per se. I guess here on Earth, we're all under the weather, as it's above us. But that's hardly a reflection on the phrase.

Comment: "under the weather" means you're not well. "under the weather too" re weather is OK for a pun that you are literally under the weather, eg buried under snow per "winter-time Finland", without necessitating illness.

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with *Blackadder*, it may be worth me pointing out that the usage in S01E05 "Witchsmeller Pursuivant" is an amusingly facetious one: *"**I'm afraid Father's feeling a bit under the weather.**" "**Oh, dear. Any idea what?**" "**Not sure. I think it's Black Death.**"* Facetious because "under the weather" (as with "a bit off-colour") applies to *minor* ailments, not probably-fatal Black Death plague.

Answer (score 21):

**as right as rain**

> In good order or good health, satisfactory, as in *He was very ill, but
> he's right as rain now,* or *If she'd only worked on it another week
> everything would have been as right as rain.* The allusion in this
> simile is unclear, but it originated in Britain, where rainy weather
> is a normal fact of life, and indeed W.L. Phelps wrote, “The
> expression 'right as rain' must have been invented by an Englishman.”
> It was first recorded in 1894.

([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/right-as-rain))

I'm just posting a lazy answer because I'm a bit under the weather, but I should be (as) right as rain by Sunday, maybe Monday. No later than Tuesday, I'll be better for the weather, at least by Wednesday. I'll probably be as sick as a dog on Thursday and as glorious as a sunbeam on Friday. It's hard to predict.

Comment: The ambivalence of the Brit (at least) to how he regards the weather is complex. I remember a preacher once noting that a paradigm shift occurs at around the age of 21 as to how one regards the snow. A different set of exclamations spring into use. // The ambivalence makes for contradictory metaphors.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I don't know about the paradigm shift at 21.  I think it depends on whether one skis or not :-)  And I am always irritated by weather people who describe our usual horribly hot & cloudless summer weather as "another nice day".

Comment: Brits skiing is new. English is not.

Answer (score 8):

You asked for British English usage...

In answer to your title...

***In the pink***

> In extremely good health and spirits.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in_the_pink)

Even in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=in+the+pink) they have it right for the first entries. After that, it is unsurprisingly  a reference to female genitalia.

Comment: Something to do with the etymology of band name British Favourite Progressive Rock band "Pink Floyd" some Floyd being in the pink, Floyd have got something to feel outstandable.

Comment: @Jere_Sumell I would love to hear about that. I count myself one of the lucky ones to have seen Pink Floyd during the "Dark Side of the Moon" tour in 1974. Fckn incredible concert. in spite of the burn victims...

Comment: I forgot the Question mark '?" at the end of line. It was meant to be a question, I don't know story behind Pink Floyd band name even I really like their music and read one biography in Finnish -translation. I'm as interested in Pink Floyd name etymology as you, Cascabel. Thinking of it by board text being public on my comment appealing for that..

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Pink Floyd took their name from those of two blues musicians, Pink Anderson and Floyd Council, when they needed a new name in a hurry. For _in the pink_, see [here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-pink.html).

Comment: @Jere_Sumell: No, "in the pink" predates Pink Floyd, and probably rock, by decades at least.  Centuries, as per Google it dates from the 16th century.

Answer (score 8):

A thematically related idiom:

> **on cloud nine** (idiomatic)
>
> Often in the phrase *on cloud nine*: a state of bliss, elation or
> happiness.
>
> - *He was on cloud nine for days after she agreed to marry him.*

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cloud_nine)]

[Collins Cobuild](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+cloud+nine) provides one suggested etymology:

> This expression is probably derived from the numbered cloud categories
> used by the US Weather Bureau. Cloud nine, cumulonimbus, is the
> highest ....

Nevertheless, it's well known in the UK.

Comment: I'm not sure this really fits as it usually, as in your example, refers to extreme happiness, rather than simply "not being under the weather".

Comment: Note that OP sees 'under the weather' as being the opposite of 'when my mood is good'.  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/under_the_weather) licenses OP's view: << **under the weather** [phrase of weather] [informal] _slightly unwell or in low spirits_ >>. I'd say it's not the default sense, though.

Comment: So, Fred's not feeling well, but his gilfriend says she'll marry him. Right now, he's under the weather, *and* on cloud nine. Mixed metaphors?

Comment: Negative feelings are always involved with 'under the weather'. Immiscible metaphors, I think. Up one minute, down the next (ambivalence).

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the many, many possible expressions—

**In fine fettle**

> If you say that someone or something is in fine fettle, you mean that they are in very good health or condition.

[[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/in-fine-fettle)]

Answer (score 7):

In keeping with the weather jokes, for something simply "*not* under the weather":

**(As) right as rain**

> *informal*: in excellent health or condition

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28as%29%20right%20as%20rain)

Comment: Your book has a better example than mine

Answer (score 4):

In a comment, Yousef Baskin wrote:

> *On top of the world, over the moon, through the roof*, but not overhead

> **On top of the world:** If you say that you feel on top of the world, you are emphasizing that *you feel extremely happy and healthy.*

[Collins Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

Another suitable antonym for **under the weather** that maintains the over/under dichotomy is **in tiptop shape**, meaning *in perfect, first-rate or excellent condition*:

> "Are you still feeling under the weather?"
>
> "No, I'm in tiptop shape."

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice answers here, but having thought about it for a bit (I am English) I'm not at all sure that it is really appropriate to talk about the "opposite" of "under the weather".

"Under the weather", as has been mentioned, means "slightly ill" and implies a little bit miserable or depressed as a result. It is exactly the kind of expression you would use about someone who has a cold, or mild flu (definitely not Covid-19).

There are multiple expressions for someone feeling "OK", not ill, not suffering from a cold, etc. But are these really *opposite* to a very specific degree of illness and slight depression or sluggishness?

Is there a word for the "absence of blue"?

Comment: If you check on 'under the weather' (in eg Lexico, [Know Your Phrase](https://knowyourphrase.com/under-the-weather)) you will see that 'slightly unwell **or** in low spirits' are two subsenses available (though doubtless there's overlap; one can certainly  feel unwell and down at the same time). Note that OP only refers to the 'low spirits' subsense.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that: I think it is very rare that it doesn't mean "ill" in practice. Of course that may be specific to my geographical/cultural context (England, UK). If that is the case, it is important to point that out to the OP who appears not to be a native English-speaker, rather than confirming her/his possibly inaccurate assumptions.

Comment: I'd usually reserve it for the poorly sense too (Oldham; UK). But one has to go with dictionary usage panels; they are less parochial in their surveying of currency than 99+% of  individuals are.

Comment: Nice catch. Weathering the weather, whatever, as remaining above it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "poorly". Although a softy Southerner for many decades I grew up in Leeds. Reference to comprehensive analyses of corpuses of texts is useful, but the site you referenced doesn't seem to give any geographical or cultural breakdowns when making its assertions, or any proof for that matter. So until further notice ...

Answer (score 0):

***In good / fine spirits***, ***gratified*** or ***elated*** are not too bad.

***Jumping for joy*** might be a bit too strong for your connotations.

I like ***chirpy*** that gives the feeling a funny little twist.

[***Lighthearted***](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk0070rlXvoyq_ICbBPDF00vyojaMxw%3A1608319816261&ei=SAPdX6afD9aR8gK01bOwCQ&q=lighthearted%20meaning&oq=lighthear&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgBMg0IABCxAxDJAxBGEPkBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOhQILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAhCRAhCTAjoFCAAQkQI6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoFCC4QsQM6CAguELEDEIMBOgIILjoECCMQJzoECC4QQzoECAAQQzoFCAAQsQM6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6EAguEMcBEKMCEBQQhwIQkwI6CAguEMcBEK8BOgsILhCxAxDHARCvAToOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CAgAELEDEMkDOgoILhCxAxCDARAKUL2gLFiuwCxgj-QsaAFwAHgAgAHUBIgBlheSAQswLjUuMS4yLjAuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab) might go very well as an opposite to the "heaviness" of your ***under the weather***. It means

> (of a person or their behaviour) cheerful or carefree.

Beware of ***light-headed***, though, it's NOT the one! [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-headed) says:

> If you feel light-headed, *you feel weak and as if you are going to lose your balance*

Comment: In a daily use I've been using "I'm fine, Thank you" despite of right manner to answer to the question "How do you do?" when some English -spoken stranger ask me my feelings.

Comment: Because you knew they meant to ask how you are in fact?

Answer (score -1):

The best antonym to "I'm feeling under the weather." is "I'm feeling great." I don't think there's an idiomatic antonym.

"I'm feeling under the weather" is equivalent to "I'm feeling dreary", so you could say "I'm feeling bright and cheery", but that would sound stilted.